# Woocommerce Analytics Revenue should be based on Paid date

Tags: woocommerce

I use Woocommerce to add orders from admin manually. Most of my clients pay after 15 to 90 days after order is created, in some cases longer than 90 days.

I notice that Woocommerce Analytics always shows revenue based on Order created date. I agree with it by one point of view as order was created on that day, so, the revenue belong there.

I think orders tab in Analytics shows it right, which is Date, Order, customer, amount, etc..

But I think Revenue should be based on order->get_paid_date() rather than created date as the money still comes in on the paid date. If Woocommerce changes the formula, it would make little to no difference for those whose orders are paid online immediately. And it will take care of those whose orders are paid later on.

Just curious, since logically Revenue is the money coming into account and Analytics>Orders tab shows Orders by created date well already.

Thanks for your input for me to understand how Woocommerce thinks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently Woocommerce Analytics does not take paid date meta into account, it considers order creation date for revenue consideration.

It depends how one looks it, it's right and wrong.

For my use, where customers pay days or months later, it's wrong. but still the order was placed on the creation date, so, the revenue should still be linked to the creation date. so, it's right too.

One thing I did was from Analytics settings, I removed some custom status of the order to exclude from Analytics, that way until the order is actually either in Pending status or Completed status, it does not consider it in revenue. Not a perfect solution, but it helps me to exclude canceled and some custom status like Quotation not be included in Revenue.

I ended up programming my own custom admin page where I pulled all orders in completed status with paid date between start and end date and did the total manually to get my actual income for the year.

Just for someone else looking for similar question, it might help.